# ClickableText Composable font color not adjusting to dark mode

Tags: textview, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I implemented a `ClickableText` composable following the explanations in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text#get-click-position). However, while all regular `Text` composables within my app properly change their color to black when Android is in light mode and to white when the system is in dark mode, this does not happen with the `ClickableText`. The text always stays black, even in dark mode.

After looking into the `Text` composable code, I found that by default, `LocalTextStyle.current` is applied as a style per default. 
So I tried to set the `ClickableText` style attribute to `LocalTextStyle.current`, but still, it did not change anything:

```
// This Composable properly adjusts to the system dark mode
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp),
    text = "Hello"
)

// But this Composable does not adjust
ClickableText(
    text = annotatedText,
    style = LocalTextStyle.current,   // What do I need to change here?
    onClick = { offset ->
        // ...   
              }
)
```

Which style do I need to apply so that the `ClickableText` color adjusts to the current theme, too?
Thanks to anyone trying to help out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
    val color = LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current)

    ClickableText(
        text = buildAnnotatedString { append("Hello") },
        style = TextStyle.Default.copy(color = color),
        onClick = {
            // ...
        }
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Any explanation to _why_ this is necessary?

Comment: That's because `ClickableText` is part of the `foundation` lib so it cannot use any of the `material` or `material3` stylings.

Comment: `LocalContentAlpha` seems to no longer exist in Material3. You can just omit it and it will work: `val color = LocalContentColor.current`